# clientWidth undefined with Javascript + motio.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Can anybody tell me why I get a deadly
`Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined` when I try to use Motio for jquery animation?

Here's my file http://twitt.ch/clouds/

The code is taken from the working panning demo at http://darsa.in/motio/

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

```
var $example = $('#panning .example');
var frame = $example.find('.example')[0];
```

to:

```
var $example = $('#panning .example');
var frame = $example.find('.frame:eq(0)');
```